# Why is my code entering a string when I explicitly convert into an int, ONLY for one specific output?

Tags: ruby

[This](http://www.codewars.com/kata/55c6126177c9441a570000cc/train/ruby) is what I'm working on right now.

Here is my code (feel free to critique it, and please do).

```
def order_weight(weights)
    weightslist = weights.split(" ")
    def convert(weight)
      weight.split("").reduce{|sum,n| sum.to_i + n.to_i}
    end

   weightsconv = weightslist.map {|weight| convert(weight)}

   weightslist.sort_by{|a| [weightsconv[weightslist.index(a)],a]}.join(" ")
end
```

This works on *everything* except the following input string: `order_weight("3 16 9 38 95 1131268 49455 347464 59544965313 496636983114762 85246814996697")`

In that case (by printing), I see that the first 3 entries in weightsconv are corrupted to "3", "7", "9". Everything else stays the same. This solved by adding a `.map{|n| n.to_i}` at the end of line 7. I don't understand why this is necessary, since I'm already converting inside the previous block. What goes wrong inside this *one* input? Is this a Ruby bug?

Answer (score 1):

reduce/inject would return a single element from the enumerable object if it only contains one element

What you can do is to first map your array elements as numbers then you don't have to rely on you reduce/inject

```
weight.split("").map(&:to_i).inject{|sum,n| sum+n}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's your bug.

From the [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) documentation:

> If you do not explicitly specify an *initial* value for *memo*, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of *memo*.

That's likely the reason you've written `sum.to_i` because `sum` is then originally a string in your case. Also if the collection has only one element (such as `["3"]`) then there is no need to invoke the block because as the documentation says the return value is the first element (which is `"3"`). Your code can be fixed by explicitly setting the initial value (to `0`):

```
a = ["3"]
i = a.reduce { |sum, n| puts 'called'; sum + n.to_i } # no output
p i # => "3"
i = a.reduce(0) { |sum, n| puts 'called'; sum + n.to_i } # => called
p i # => 3
```

If you want your code reviewed, try [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The biggest code smell is the definition of a method inside another method. Use a lambda or get rid of it instead.